# Is $\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}(x^3+3x^2-\frac{\sin (ax)}a)$ a polynomial function?

Tags: functions, polynomials

$$\color{blue}{f(x)=\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\left(x^3+3x^2-\frac{\sin (ax)}a\right)}$$

if we look at this at a glance then using the basic understanding that $\sin x$ will always vary between -1 and 1 then we can say that $\sin (ax)/a$ will be zero as $a$ tends to infinity and hence $f(x)$ will be a polynomial function.

But,

$$\sin x= x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-...$$
$$\therefore \frac{\sin ax}{a}=\frac 1a\left(x-\frac{a^3x^3}{3!}+\frac{a^5x^5}{5!}-...\right)=\left(\frac xa-\frac{a^2x^3}{3!}+\frac{a^4x^5}{5!}-...\right)$$
So, if $a$ tends to infinity then it is not going to be zero because 1/a will be zero and the consecutive two terms will be always positive, so I don't think it will be zero. so if this happens then $f(x)$ will not be a polynomial. So this is contradiction.

But what i think that the second reasoning **might** be wrong but i don't know what is wrong because i have heard that infinite series show some different behavior, but you know what, i don't think i have reasoned wrong, or have i?

So is $f(x)$ a polynomial function?

Comment: yes, the pointwise limit is a polynomial (the sin part goes to zero). The Taylor series argument is misleading if you truncate and then take the limit. This is not interchangeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No matter what $x$ is, once fixed $x^3+3x^2$ does not depend on $a$ and $\lvert \sin(ax) \rvert \leq 1$, so you have
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty} \left(x^3+3x^2 - \frac{\sin(ax)}{a}\right)
= x^3+3x^2 - \lim_{a\to\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{a}
= x^3+3x^2 -  0 = x^3+3x^2
$$
since $\lim_{a\to\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{a} = 0$ by the squeeze theorem. (as by the above, $\lvert \frac{\sin(ax)}{a}\rvert \leq \frac{1}{a}$).

So your function $f$ is exactly defined as
$$
f(x) = x^3+3x^2.
$$

*Your confusion comes from looking at the power series for $\sin$, and arguing about the limit term by term without considering the cancellations that may (and do) occur.*